# SQL (Big Query) count unique users matching 1 criteria as subset of zip code

Tags: google-bigquery

I have created a query that counts users matching set criteria in each zip code.  What I need is a count of users matching a specific additional criteria (type) within each zip code.  I am stumped, I can get a county by type but not of users with 1 or more entries in each zip (e.g. if User 2 has 2 entries I only want to count 1).  Appreciate any and all help.

```
SELECT 
 home_postal_code, 
 COUNT(home_postal_code) as zip_code, 
 type
 FROM `dim_member` dm
  inner join `fact_tracking` fw
  on dm.member_id = fw.member_id
 where classic_country = "US"
  and cast(active as string) like '%true%'
  and fw.tracked_date_id >= 20220801
 group by home_postal_code, type
 order by zip_code desc
```

Sample Data:

| postal_code | Tracked_date_id | User_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08853 | 20220815 | 123-456-789 |
| 08853 | 20220817 | 123-456-789 |
| 45677 | 20220824 | 234-567-890 |
| 08853 | 20220430 | 987-654-321 |

Expected Output:

| Zip_code | Zip_Code_Count | User_Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08853 | 2 | 1 |
| 45677 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Can you share your sample and expected data?

Comment: postal_code     Tracked_date_id       User_id
08853                20220815                  123-456-789
08853                20220817                  123-456-789
45677                20220824                 234-567-890
08853                20220430                 987-654-321

I'd expect to see
Zip_code        Zip_Code_Count  User_Count
08853                      2                         1
45677                       1                         0

Comment: @NoelaniDiemicke Can you confirm whether the answer below solved your problem or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Based from your sample data. Consider the approach below:

```sql
with sample_data as (
            select 08853 as postal_code, 20220815 as tracked_date_id, '123-456-789' as user_id
  union all select 08853 as postal_code, 20220817 as tracked_date_id, '123-456-789' as user_id
  union all select 45677 as postal_code, 20220824 as tracked_date_id, '234-567-890' as user_id
  union all select 08853 as postal_code, 20220430 as tracked_date_id, '987-654-321' as user_id

),
remove_dups as (
select 
  distinct
  postal_code,
  user_id,
from sample_data
)
select 
  postal_code as zip_code,
  count(postal_code) as zip_code_count,
  count(user_id) - 1 as user_count
from remove_dups
  group by postal_code
```

Output:

[image]

NOTE: Answers is based on the limited data and might not cover all use cases.